# Changing SRC in Javascript by clicking on link

Tags: javascript, video, hyperlink, youtube, modal-dialog

I've found a javascript on the web that shows modal window with video when user clicks on a link. Everything works great with one video, but when I add another link for different video it just opens that youtube adress without modal window. The script adds html code on a click after the modal window loads, like this:

```
var modalHTML = '<div id="modalbackground"></div><iframe id="' + vidFrameId +
                '" src="' ??? '" width="' + vidSize.width + '" height="' + 
                vidSize.height + '" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

and the video links are like this:

```
<a id="videoLink" href="https://www.youtube.com/v/jHbyQ_AQP8c">aaa</a>
<a id="videoLink" href="https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/UrJORkUaOkk">bbb</a>
```

So my question is, what should I put in var modalHTML src field? I tried with `"' this.href '"` and it works only for first link, second link goes to youtube page?

Comment: Here is the full code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kf5HJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can get clicked link href like this

```
    $(".dummyClass").click(function () {
            var clickedSrc= $(this).attr("href");               
            var modalHTML = '<div id="modalbackground"></div><iframe id="' + vidFrameId +
                '" src="' +clickedSrc+'" width="' + vidSize.width + '" height="' + 
                vidSize.height + '" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>'
        });
```

**And make sure you have unique id for Each element**,  for selector i had put one `dummyClass` so that same can be used as selector

```
<a id="videoLink1" class="dummyClass" href="https://www.youtube.com/v/jHbyQ_AQP8c">aaa</a>
<a id="videoLink2" class="dummyClass" href="https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/UrJORkUaOkk">bbb</a>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use only Javascript, and when I change ID's nothing works anymore... I was thinking there is some fast and easier way, but I guess there isn't :) Thanks anyway!